# Nullpointerexception in MessageBroker

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

```
while (true) {  

    Message message = consumer.receive();

    if (message != null) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
        try{
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        System.out.println("Received message '"+ textMessage.getText() + "'");
        msg.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        msg.setBody(textMessage.getText());
        msgBroker.routeMessageToService(msg, null);

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        } else {
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

while trying to run this 
`msgBroker.routeMessageToService(msg, null)` throws `NullPointerException`.

Can anyone give best solution?

Comment: Maybe because your `msgBroker` is null?

Answer (score 0):

Either msgBroker is null or one of the parameters being passed into msgBroker.routeMessageToService() is. Without the stack trace printed when the exception is caught, it's hard to tell where the problem is - with it, it will identify exactly which variable is null when it shouldn't be.

From your code, and given the fact that msg can't be null (or the exception would have occurred earlier) it's that either msgBroker is null, the null being passed in to msgBroker is doing the damage, or that the code inside msgBroker.routeMessageToService() has a bug.

A more robust version of your code is:

```
while (true) {  
    Message message = consumer.receive();
    //Note extra variables being checked here
    if (message != null && msg != null && msgBroker != null) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try{
                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                System.out.println("Received message '"+ textMessage.getText() + "'");
                msg.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                msg.setBody(textMessage.getText());
                msgBroker.routeMessageToService(msg, null);
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception is throws at the line msgBroker.routeMessageToService(msg, null);

Comment: Actually considering that null is an allowed value for the 2nd parameter and msg can't be null at this point the only possible explanation is that msgBroker is null itself.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible explanation is that your msgBroker is NULL. msg obviously exists (otherwise you'd get errors earlier) and null is an allowed value for the 2nd parameter to routeMessageToService.

Comment: i have used, private static MessageBroker msgBroker=null;

Comment: May i know how to get the MessageBroker value.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue in my application. The null pointer exception is due to security-constraint in messaging-config.xml. After removing security-constraint  for the destination in messaging-config.xml file it worked for me.